# Bundling an updated Realm seed-file?

Tags: swiftui, realm

I have successfully created a seed.realm-file and bundled it with my app with the following code-snippet:

```
init() {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "seed", withExtension: "realm") else { fatalError("Could not find seed") }
    realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 1, seedFilePath: url))
}
```

How would I get realm to seed from a new updated seed-file when I'm releasing an updated app-version? After doing some testing it seems Realm is happy as long as it got a default.realm in the Document-folder, and will ignore the seed-file once the default.realm is created.

The default.realm is created from the seed-file the first time the app runs. Can I somehow create the seed-file with a new build number or something, so that the above code will automatically recreate the default.realm-file when it detects a new build?

I was thinking of creating a UserDefault-key containing the build-number the first time the app is launched. Then comparing this key with the current app-build, and if different, deleting the default.realm-file before calling:

```
realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 1, seedFilePath: url))
```

Would that be a proper way of doing it? I have searched the Realm-documentation, but can't find any strategy how to handle this.

The app connects to an API to fetch new data, but I still want to include an updated database from time to time when releasing a new app-version to reduce network-traffic.

Comment: It seems like you're almost there but the question is a little incomplete. So for reference, the concept when bundling a realm is: 1) Create a Realm file and drag it into your XCode project. 2) In code, open the bundled Realm using seedFilePath 3) delete the existing default.realm 4) read in the objects from the bundled realm 5) write the objects to default.realm. When that's done, the schema version will reset because the default.realm was deleted. Based on those steps, where are you having difficulty?

Comment: Thanks, should you do this every time the app is launched? Or what kind of check should you run to see if the bundled seed is newer than the default.realm? And how do you separate user data models (which shouldn't be deleted) from read only data models (which should be populated from the seed)? Let's say you have a Product-model which is updated from the seed/api, and a FavouriteProduct which is populated by the user.

Comment: The answer depends on the use case; what do YOU want to happen if a or b or c? For example, suppose the seed has 10 objects. On first launch, the default.realm with have 10 objects. If on next launch the default.realm has 11 objects, does that make it newer because it was recently updated? Because it has more objects? What if the seed objects are the same? It's an app design question more than anything. A "Version" object would be a simple solution - whenever the app launches, compare the bundled seed Version object with the Version object in the default.realm. Then decide how to handle that.

Answer (score -1):

I don’t have the answer, but in preloading a realm file there are a number of details missing in the recommendations from the mongodb site. Although I can successfully load a bundle and see the data replaced in the default realm, my app creates a fatal error. So the app is not working. The issue is that the configuration must have read only set to true for the data to show, and you must set a schema version. The schema version is the problem as the copy of the bundle is resetting the version. Setting the version to 0 will cause tons of errors on the properties. Setting to 1 or higher causes a fatal error. Not setting a schema value will also create an error. If anyone has an idea how to make this work would be appreciated!

Comment: It's best to not post questions as answers and this answer is pretty vague. For example, the post says - *"my app creates a fatal error."*. That's due to a bug in your code? Also note that setting the config to readOnly for the bundled Realm is so it's not modified; to modify, it needs to be copied it to a folder by setting the seedFilePath. The schema version of the bundled realm is unrelated to existing data as the idea is to copy the data from the bundle to your own; the schema version doesn't matter for that process. I would suggest posting a question with code and we'll try to help!